# set custom formatting for vim sqlutilies plugin

Tags: sql, vim, formatting

Using the [sqlutilies](https://github.com/vim-scripts/SQLUtilities) plugin in vim for reformatting a number of large and **messy** sql scripts and I would like to put the column names in my select statements on separate lines to increase readability, but would prefer the comma separating the column names to be plavced at the end of the line. I currently have:

`let g:sqlutil_align_comma = 1`

in my .vimrc, which does the formatting job just fine, but as I said, i'd like to put the comma at the end of the line rather than at the start, which would invalidate the alignment on comma...

There is note on customisation in the docs but I'm struggling to understand how to approach the problem.